# PhP Contact form in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email, contacts

So I bought a theme that has a simple PHP contact form that allows users to message each other, but when a sender fills out the form and submits it, the email comes from my default Wordpress Admin email and not the email address the user inputs in the form. So if the receiver tries to reply to their email, it's going to come to me (Admin) and not the person who sent the email.

Am I missing something here...seems pretty straight forward. I've tried changing it up and using $headers, etc., but nothing works... always just comes from my admin email.

Here is the form code:

```
<form method="post"><input type="hidden" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>" name="pid_rep" />
     <li>
        <h3><?php echo __('Your Email'); ?>:</h3>
    <p><input type="text" size="50" class="do_input"  name="email" /></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3><?php echo __('Message'); ?>:</h3>
    <p><textarea rows="4" cols="40" class="do_input" name="message"></textarea>
    <<input type="submit" name="contact" value="<?php _e('Send Message'); ?>" /></p>
    </li>
</form>
```

Here is the handler:

```
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = nl2br($_POST['message']);
```

Comment: Could you send the complete code?

Comment: This is the way things are *supposed* to work. If your website sends an email purporting to come from another web domain, it will most likely be rejected as spam before anyone can read it. The correct way to do things is put the sender's email address in a `Reply-To` header. Your contact form handler may already be doing this.

Comment: Here is the whole section of code. I should mention that this is for a classifieds website, so the point is that a potential buyer is contacting a seller.

Comment: okay it says the whole code is too long

Comment: but the rest of it doesn't have anything to do with it...

Answer (score 0):

As I know it is a WordPress security setting and you can't change it. The email sender's domain name must be equal with your website domain name.
Possible to define a custom, even not existing sender email address and sender name, you can do it with this plugin: [WordPress Contact Form Slider](http://wordpresscontactform.com)